# Trying to get data from a webhook with php json

Tags: php, arrays, debugging, webhooks

I'm trying to download a file, which URL I get from a webhook:

```
 <?php
$webhookResponse = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

//The resource that we want to download.
$fileUrl = $webhookResponse["data"]["orderDetails"][0]["detailFiles"][0]["fileUrl"];

//The path & filename to save to.
$saveTo = 'test.pdf';

//Open file handler.
$fp = fopen($saveTo, 'w+');

//If $fp is FALSE, something went wrong.
if($fp === false){
    throw new Exception('Could not open: ' . $saveTo);
}

//Create a cURL handle.
$ch = curl_init($fileUrl);

//Pass our file handle to cURL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

//Timeout if the file doesn't download after 20 seconds.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

//Execute the request.
curl_exec($ch);

//If there was an error, throw an Exception
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

//Get the HTTP status code.
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//Close the cURL handler.
curl_close($ch);

//Close the file handler.
fclose($fp);

if($statusCode == 200){
    echo 'Downloaded!';
} else{
    echo "Status Code: " . $statusCode;
}
?>
```

When I try to run it, it gives me an error:

**Trying to access array offset on value of type null**

This is how my array looks that I get from webhook:

[image]

Interesting thing, if I put this same script on another server, it works fine, it downloads the file, if I put it one the actual one I need to use (ubuntu, nginx) it gives me this error, could this be a little server related?

Comment: Doesn't sounds secure to auto download file by remotely sent URL to 1 of your pages.  The issue is with file_get_contents('php://input'), there a few possible reasons why it is empty > probably the server is configured with some proxy structure (nginx/apache/php) ?

Comment: It's just a clean ubuntu+LEMP setup, no fancy configurations.

Comment: Depending on the type of the request it may not show up in php input > consider using $_POST / $_GET or even $_REQUEST if it can be both ..

Comment: So I'd just be replacing the whole php://input line with something like this?:
$name = $_GET["data"]["orderDetails"][0]["detailFiles"][0]["fileUrl"];

Sorry, I'm quite bad at this, as you probably can tell.

Comment: If you are waiting for GET data yes, if you wait for POST data use $_POST or just use $_REQUEST ..

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, with POST and REQUEST. By the way, one thing I forgot to mention is that the parameters in my webhook are passed as a JSON/Application, so I suppose the top line with json_decode...php://input is pretty important?